# Unable to install openjdk in Fedora

Tags: java, linux, installation, fedora

I referred the official doc to install openjdk : https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/installing-java/

First searched the package:

```
[user@server]$ dnf search openjdk

================================================================= Name & Summary Matched: openjdk ==================================================================
java-latest-openjdk.x86_64 : OpenJDK 18 Runtime Environment
java-latest-openjdk-demo.x86_64 : OpenJDK 18 Demos
java-latest-openjdk-demo-fastdebug.x86_64 : OpenJDK 18 Demos optimised with full debugging on
java-latest-openjdk-demo-slowdebug.x86_64 : OpenJDK 18 Demos unoptimised with full debugging on
java-latest-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK 18 Development Environment
```

Then I tried to installed the first one but got error

```
[user@server]$ sudo dnf install java-latest-openjdk.x86_64

Envoyproxy Official Repository - tetrate-getenvoy-rpm-stable                                                                        2.6 kB/s | 1.4 kB     00:00    
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libXtst.so.6()(64bit) needed by java-latest-openjdk-1:18.0.1.0.10-1.rolling.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libgif.so.7()(64bit) needed by java-latest-openjdk-1:18.0.1.0.10-1.rolling.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libXcomposite(x86-64) needed by java-latest-openjdk-1:18.0.1.0.10-1.rolling.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 needed by java-latest-openjdk-1:18.0.1.0.10-1.rolling.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Download JDK 18 tar from https://jdk.java.net/18/ for your arch, untar to your preferred location and run `java -version`

Comment: I don't use Fedora but it looks to me that your package manager is not configured right in respect to repositories (at least). You should be seeing the vanilla openjdk there as well